# consulta SQL entre dos tablas SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo dos tablas (tb_Producto_M y tb_Producto_Producto) que presenta una recursividad, donde un Producto puede tener varios Producto hijos. En la tabla tb_Producto_Producto contiene los datos del id_Producto_padre que Productos hijos tiene este. Necesito realizar una consulta que me muestre el id_Producto, det_Producto según el id_producto_padre.

```
 ---------------                        
|tb_Producto   |                        
----------------                          
|id_Producto   |                         
|det_Producto  |                         
---------------    


----------------------
|tb_Producto_Producto|
|id_Producto_Padre   | 
|id_Producto_hijo    | 
---------------------
```

Comment: uf, no está tan sencillo entender tu necesidad. Puedes postear datos de ejemplo y el resultado que quieres en base a esos datos?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que necesitas es hacer un **JOIN** con tus tablas que seria algo así:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_Producto_Producto
INNER JOIN tb_Producto ON tb_Producto.id_Producto = tb_Producto_Producto.id_Producto_Padre
```

Comment: Esto asume que hay sólo un nivel de jerarquía

Comment: Así ya que al menos hasta donde entendí solo hay un nivel en profundidad.

Answer (score 2):

algo asi ?
segun la poca informacion que das, entendi que quieres hacer esto:

```
select * from tb_Producto   
where id_Producto   in (
select id_Producto_hijo  from tb_Producto_Producto 
where  id_Producto_Padre   = id_queBuscas_padre
)
```

Comment: No puedo creer que después de tanto tiempo empleando sql, nunca haya usado **IN** hehehe nunca se deja de aprender.

Comment: haha, si la respuesta es correcta, ponta como solucionada. Gracias

Comment: Considera que `IN` toma mayor tiempo en la ejecución de la consulta